# Problemas com o javascript e google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variáveis

Estou tentando calcular a distância entre esses dois pontos mas não estou conseguindo! Gostaria de descobrir qual o problema.

No console, dá erro um 404:

> ```
> distancia.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
>     at distancia.html:14
> (anonymous) @ distancia.html:14
> ```

Que é essa linha aqui:

```js
var nyc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.715, -74.002);
```

Eis o código todo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <script>

            var nyc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.715, -74.002);
            var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.506, -0.119);
            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(nyc, london);


            function myFunction() {
                alert(distance);
            }
        </script>
       <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD9A0ThwdhnBC2wLskwCmpWV5aFP1A05pU&libraries=geometry"
    async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Tmc Veja isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/132 - Foi essa uma das razões que me levou a rejeitar isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/129525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD9A0ThwdhnBC2wLskwCmpWV5aFP1A05pU&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>

        var nyc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.715, -74.002);
        var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.506, -0.119);
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(nyc, london);


        
            alert(distance);
        
    </script>
   
</body>
```

Tenta assim

Comment: Obrigado! Poderia me explicar sua resposta mais um pouco! Quer dizer que o erro era apenas a posição das tags do javascript?

Comment: @PenaPintada, Sim, Voce sempre tem que respeitar as posicoes

Comment: Voce precisa carregar o arquivo javascript (no seu caso o googleapis) antes de poder usar suas funções.
Quando quiser colocar o carregamento no fim da pagina você precisa usar um método que execute seu código javascript somente depois que o documento estiver carregado. Que no caso é o `window.document.onload = function(e){}`

Comment: @Sérginho Obrigado cara! Não sabia disso por incrível que pareça!

Answer (score 1):

Se você incluiu os atributos `async defer` na tag `<script>`, o ideal seria puxar a variável `distance` à partir de uma função. Isso porque se você colocar a variável `distance` no `alert`, essa variável ainda não foi definida no carregamento da página, isso porque a API está **assíncrona**.

A função que puxa seu `alert`:

```
function pegaDistancia(){
    var nyc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.715, -74.002);
    var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.506, -0.119);
    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(nyc, london);
    return distance;
}

function myFunction() {
    alert(pegaDistancia());
}
```

```js
function pegaDistancia(){
 var nyc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.715, -74.002);
 var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.506, -0.119);
 var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(nyc, london);
 return distance;
}

function myFunction() {
 alert(pegaDistancia());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD9A0ThwdhnBC2wLskwCmpWV5aFP1A05pU&libraries=geometry" async defer></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado cara! Ótima explicação , Dei um voto ai para a sua resposta!

Comment: Seria possível construir com o google maps API um programa que passado um raio qualquer como parâmetro ele retorne os pontos que pertencem a aquele circulo gerado pelo raio? O que eu deveria usar? Vou apagar essa comentario!!

Comment: @PenaPintada Obg pelo voto! Cara, não sei te dizer, não sou especialista em Google Maps. Só consegui responder a sua pergunta pq ela envolve mais lógica de programação do que o Maps em si.

Comment: Valeu então,  de qualquer forma ajudou cara!

Comment: @PenaPintada Ah, só mais uma coisa pra adicionar à minha resposta: quando vc define a API assíncrona, tanto faz vc chamar a API no início como no fim da página. Já o contrário, a API deve ser chamada antes da funções. Valeu!